# Symfony and Twig templates. How to dynamically extend a template or extend nothing?

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig

Let me describe a situation. You have a profile form and a form where users can upload personal profile related documents. Since the profile form is already very long the documents moved to a new form.

Everything works great. Now we want to use the bootstrap tabs to do Profile | Documents for user friendliness.

Now I know because we are using two separate forms if you submit the documents the changes on the profile won't save and vice versa.

I have added the document form in the tab using

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="documents">
    {{ render(controller('ManyAppBundle:Document:createDocument', {'viewOnly': true})) }}
</div>
```

The 'viewOnly': true is a query parameter and is not required by the action.

My question now becomes if the profile tab renders the document template it must only show the upload widget and the submit where as when you go directly to the document page it must show the title and side bar and everything.

So I tried

```
{% if not viewOnly %}
    {% extends ... %}
{% endif %}
```

That gave problems because you can't use extends within a if(Causes a ("Node "1" does not exist for Node "Twig_Node".") error).

Other similar question provided this solution

```
{% extends viewOnly == false ? ... %}
```

When viewOnly is false it must extend the base template used by all other templates but if it is true I only want to show this:

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'style': 'horizontal', 'col_size': 'sm' }) }}
    {% if form.documents is defined %}
        {{ form_row(form.documents) }}
    {% endif %}

    {{ form_row(form.submit, { 'attr': { 'class': 'btn btn-success' } }) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

But now with the top

```
{% extends viewOnly == false ? ... %}
```

if viewOnly becomes true it fails with Template "" can't be find.

Is there a way to say extends this specific template that will be the same result of not extending any template?

Or alternatively is there a way of saying extend this when viewOnly is false or just do nothing?

Comment: After the first answer came in from @Jeet I do believe my question is not stated clearly. If you do not extend another template you get that default everything is to the left no styling look. That is what I want, I want a way to say IF this EXTENDS this else do absolutely nothing. If it is not suppose to extend a template then it must not try to extend anything at all. Making a new template file with nothing in, to extend does not feel like it is the proper way to achieve this.

Comment: I do appreciate the different ways you guys have given examples of Jeet and Thomas. I do believe that my question was wrong to start off with what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically 3 solutions to determine how to switch between extending different types of templates within a twig template.

The first will be a very simple true or false logic based. You can do this within the twig file easily as in the following example

```
{% extends entity.isExpired == false ? active.html.twig : expired.html.twig %}
```

The second will be as @Jeet suggested doing this in a controller. This can also be as simple as a boolean check but as advanced as additional entity  checks as in the following example

```
/* User Controller */
public function showAction($id)
{
    $user = $this->get('myapp.repository.user')->findBy($id);
    $isUser = $user instanceof User;

    if (!$isUser) {
        return $this->redirectToBloggersPage();
    }

    /* $params is what you will normally return to the template */
    $params = array (
        'user' => $user,
    );

    if ($user->hasPostedBlog()) {
        $params['blog'] = $this->get('myapp.repository.blog')->findByUserLatest($user);

        return $this->render('MyAppBundle:User:user_and_blog_view.html.twig', $params);
    }
    else {
        return $this->render('MyAppBundle:User:user_view.html.twig', $params);
    }
}
```

The third will be as @Thomas suggested doing this in a separate twig function. This will be done in a Twig extension where you can inject services as in the following example

```
/* Twig extension */
public function extendBookForm()
{
    if ($this->getSecurityContext()->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        return "user_view.html.twig";
    }

    return "public_view.html.twig";
}

/* Twig file */
{% extends extend_book_from() %}
```

My original question does not have a solution for the outcome I wanted. I am taking it that the way I hoped for is not possible and if you dynamically want to check what to extend you must always extend more than one template since you will have to extend something for each outcome.

These are the different ways you will be able to do dynamic template extensions.

Comment: Actually, you can simply put that logic in your controller and add a variable to twig. The in the template, `extends TEMPLATE_PATH_VARIABLE`

Answer (score 3):

The logic should sit in the controller action.

What you can do is create 2 twigs, a parent twig that extends and includes another child twig that have data.

In your controller, based on condition you can render the extended twig or the child one.

In your case, controller code might be something like this :

```
if ($request->query->get('view-only') === true) {
    return $this->render('MyAppBundle:Default:data.html.twig'); // this twig hasn't extended; only data.
}
else {
    return $this->render('MyAppBundle:Default:index.html.twig'); // this twig has data.html.twig included and extended.
}
```

I hope that fixes your issue. :)

Comment: The main problem is when you create a new template and you do not call extends there is nothing and even the bootstrap code is not there. It really just gives this crappy default everything to the left unformatted layout. I want that, I don't want to make a new template that doesn't define anything and extend that one. Is there not a way to say extends this or do not try to extend anything at all

Comment: Above solution should never get you non-extended twigs on fresh page request. I guess a request parameter 'view-only' is available if its an ajax request for the tab data, in that case you have to return only data, not whole page layout. So the above condition in your controller action will get you accordingly when an ajax request passed through it.

Comment: Ok @Jeet I understand that part create 2 templates where one extends the main and the other just shows the data but then what is the point of being able to do non controller based logic in a template if you have to do most of the main template logic still in the controller? This doesn't feel optimal. Your suggestion will lead to 3 twig files where one contains the form and it's layout, the one will contain the extends ... includes(form) and the third will just includes(form). Do you see why I am thinking there must be another way

Comment: Well, the above solution I choose becase the extended twig with wrapper element can be separated from html formatted data that will be returned by ajax, If there would be another solution, it would be nice to have. :)

Comment: Also, I don't see need of a 3rd twig unless your ajax call requires any diffrennt set of data.

Comment: there is currently no 2nd template. This is not a ajax call either. All I wanted was to display the form on the profile form, if you make a mistake on the document form it will go to the static page of the document upload process.(This side does not have to change). So one template will have the extends and the extra sidebar data and and and plus the actual form and it's layout. Where the second one will only contain the form layout. So to save the form layout in a single place both will include the _form.html.twig. This means the one template to use will end up only being include(_form)

Answer (score 1):

Although I like Jeet's solution better, here is more complicated alternative. Keep in mind, this solution is only educational.

1. [Create a new Twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#reference-dic-tags-twig-extension) (if you don't already have one).
2. [Inject the request](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#injecting-the-request) into your extension.
3. Create a Twig function `extend_from` (see below for sample code) that returns the template based on the request.
4. Call the Twig function into the extend block.

The Twig function could like the following:

```
/**
 * Returns the template to be extended
 * Notes: Code assumes that the request data is a protected property
 *        on the Twig extension.
 *
 * @param  string  $template = "full.html.twig"  the full layout template
 * @return string  the template to be extended
 */
public function extendFrom($template = "full.html.twig")
{
    if ($this->request->query->get('view-only') === true) {
        return "empty_layout.html.twig";
    }

    return $template;
}
```

In your template:

```
{# Templates assumes that your extended templates have a "content block" #}
{% extends extend_from() %}

{% block content %}
    {# Your template content here #}
{% endblock %}
```

It's a bit of "magic" solution to me. The best approach is to consider your content as a module. Either you render it alone or you include into your layout.

In [my project](https://github.com/teapotio/teapotio-forum) for example:

1. I create a [page template](https://github.com/teapotio/teapotio-forum/blob/master/src/Teapotio/SiteBundle/Resources/themes/teapotio-forum-classic/TeapotioForumBundle/page/message/list.html.twig) + a [partial template](https://github.com/teapotio/teapotio-forum/blob/master/src/Teapotio/SiteBundle/Resources/themes/teapotio-forum-classic/TeapotioForumBundle/partial/message/list.html.twig).
2. The page template includes the partial template which includes a bunch of modules.
3. When the user navigates around the site I ajax and load the partial template in the already-rendered page.

In the future, I can render the entire page, part of the page or just one of the modules in that page.

It's a bit complicated but it becomes very powerful with these [BaseThemeBundle](https://github.com/teapotio/BaseThemeBundle) which allows me to override any templates.

Comment: I do like the way you put that into a function and this will help me with additional solutions where logic becomes complicated. Although with this simple case you can simply use {% extends viewOnly == false ? empty_layout.html.twig : full.html.twig %} as in my original post. I will still have to create the empty_layout.html.twig. I was just hoping that there will be a way of doing this without creating the essentially empty layout template.

Comment: I am sure the empty layout will become useful at some point in the development of your project. In my project, I had to refactor everything because I wanted a default wrapper for all my partial content.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was to create an empty.html view with just this in it

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Not a great solution, but much simpler than some of the other methods, so I don't have to add more clutter.