# Is it possible to implement an index.php file that can show one or other Twig template?

Tags: php, templates, session, twig

Let's say we have to manage user login and logout.

We have an index.php file that by default shows the index.twig template (which contains a header to allow users login or signup.

And we have another Twig template (welcome.twig) that's similar to index.twig template but, its header shows access to user profile, logout option and operations that our user can do on the website.

I'd like to know if the index.php file can show one of both of those templates by a conditional.

In my index.php file I've got this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['account'])){
     $twig->display("index.twig");
}else{
     $twig->display("welcome.twig");
}
```

As you may know, I am telling to show index.twig (the default template) when account is NOT set in $_SESSION variable, and to show welcome.twig when account is set in $_SESSION variable.

Account set on $_SESSION variable occurs in other file called login.php

For now, I've been using a second file (welcome.php) to get what I want, but I'm not sure about this is a good way to get it...

Thanks.

Comment: Why should not it be possible? Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't figure out how... That's because I'm asking here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across with this one solution:

I setted a value to the $_SESSION variable in my index.php file

```
<?php

            require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
            require_once '../generated-conf/config.php';
            require_once '../vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
            session_start(); // Session always starts when index.php is loaded (even if it is loaded for the first time)
            Twig_Autoloader::register();


            $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates/');
            $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

            // Condition to show any or other template
            if (isset($_SESSION['online']) && ($_SESSION['online'] == true)){
                $args= array('online' => true, 'session' => $_SESSION);
            }else{
                $args= array('online' => false);
            }
            // Display Twig template
            $twig->display("index.twig", $args);

?>
```

And in my Twig template (index.twig):

```
{% if online == true %} {# It's not the $_SESSION variable 'online' value, but the 'online' value of the 'args' array #}
     {% include 'userMenu.twig' %}
{% else %}
     {% include 'defaultMenu.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```

That's making it work :)

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: You can do more simple: {% include online ? 'userMenu.twig' : 'defaultMenu.twig' %}

Answer (score 2):

You should use conditional inheritance on your template. Look at this answer:

[Twig extend template on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861438/twig-extend-template-on-condition)

You can pass a variable to the template, like this:

```
$twig->display("index.twig", array('logged' => isset($_SESSION['account'])));
```

And then, do the condition in template with that variable. It can inherit from two templates, each with a different menu, depending if the user is logged or not.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I did something like you said (same idea).  I'll post the solution in Answer section shortly. Thanks for your answer :)