# Symfony : Cancelling extends if variable is null or false

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to ignore extends in twig if variable is false

```
{% if variable %}
    {% extends 'MyBundle::template.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}

{% if not admin %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endif %}
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there a way out to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig extend template on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861438/twig-extend-template-on-condition)

Comment: It works if we have else tag. In my case, I have if without else

Comment: Can't be done without `else`. Just use a minimal template in order to make this work